# Return the "Name" of an object that has a specific "Value" in PSObject

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, properties, psobject

I have converted a JSON file to a PSObject using:

```
$json = Get-Content $filepath -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

An example of what is now in the PSObject:

```
Value           : Production
MemberType      : NoteProperty
IsSettable      : True
IsGettable      : True
TypeNameOfValue : System.String
Name            : Environment
IsInstance      : True
```

I know you can get the Value of this by using:

```
$json.psobject.properties["Environment"].Value
```

This will return "Production"

**Question**:

Is there a way to get the Name returned based on the value like how I am able to get the Value returned based on the name as shown above?

**I.e. How can i get "Environment" returned?**

For background I am writing a script that will loop through all the values and if the values are empty then i need to print the Names.

Comment: `($json | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq 'Production'}).Name`

Comment: thanks @Theo ! Just had to change $json to $json.psobject.properties and it worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

With [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo)'s help you've already found the solution, but let me spell it out, with some background information:

```
# Read a sample object from JSON text.
$fromJson = @'
{
  "Foo": "Bar",
  "Environment": "Production",
  "Other": "Stuff"
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

# Find the name of the property/ies whose value is 'Production'
# -> 'Environment'
$fromJson.psobject.Properties.Where({ $_.Value -eq 'Production' }).Name
```

Note:

- The above relies on the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject) that PowerShell exposes on all objects, which is a rich source of reflection, such as on a given object's properties via `.psobject.Properties`, as well as on the [intrinsic `.Where()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) for filtering (a better-performing, feature-richer alternative to the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) *cmdlet*).
- The **code only works for *top-level* properties** of the object(s) parsed from JSON. If you need **to search an entire object *graph***, i.e. *nested* objects for values at any level of the hierarchy, more effort is needed.

The following example assumes that function `Get-PropertyPathByValue` has already been defined (see below):

```
# Read a *nested* sample object from JSON text.
$fromJson = @'
{
  "Foo": "Bar",
  "Nested": {
    "More": "Stuff",
    "Environment": "Production"
  },
  "Other": "Stuff"
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

# Find the value 'Production' anywhere in the object hierarchy,
# and return the matching property's name *path* (dot notation).
# -> 'Nested.Environment'
$fromJson | Get-PropertyPathByValue -Value 'Production'
```

**`Get-PropertyPathByValue` source code** - note the limitation on what types of values can be searched for:

```
# Finds a *simple* value in the object graphs given and returns the path of 
# matching properties in dot notation (e.g., 'foo.bar`).
# Note: *Simple* means a *single* (non-collection) value that is either:
#  * a string or
#  * an instance of a .NET primitive or similar type (numbers, dates).
function Get-PropertyPathByValue {
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)] [AllowNull()]  [object] $InputObject, [Parameter(Mandatory)] [AllowNull()] $Value, [string] $NamePath)
  process {   
    if ($null -eq $InputObject -or $InputObject.GetType().IsPrimitive -or $InputObject.GetType() -in [string], [datetime], [datetimeoffset], [decimal], [bigint]) {
      # A null-like value or a primitive / quasi-primitive type -> output.
      if ($Value -eq $InputObject) { return $NamePath }
    }
    elseif ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -and $InputObject -isnot [System.Collections.IDictionary]) {
      # A collection of sorts (other than a string or dictionary (hash table)), 
      # recurse on its elements.
      $i = 0
      foreach ($o in $InputObject) { Get-PropertyPathByValue $o $Value ($NamePath + '[' + $i++ + ']') }
    }
    else { 
      # A non-quasi-primitive scalar object or a dictionary:
      # enumerate its properties / entries.
      $props = if ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]) { $InputObject.GetEnumerator() } else { $InputObject.psobject.properties }
      $sep = '.' * ($NamePath -ne '')
      foreach ($p in $props) {
        Get-PropertyPathByValue $p.Value $Value ($NamePath + $sep + $p.Name)
      }
    }
  }
}
```